# how to write a css that only can be visible on desktop in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I rewrote a declaration

```
 .navbar .nav {
    top:30px;
}
```

on the my css file, but I only want this declaration can be responded on desktop view, not in the phone veiw. How do I to write correctly? thank your help.

Comment: BY assigning .nav class top:30px will have aligning problem . Do you want to position your navbar aT 30px from top.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here: the power of media queries:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1079px) {

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {

}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {

}
```

Comment: Given the CSS in the poster's example `top:30px` you should add at least one `max-height` example.

Comment: You can put custom sizes... this are the ones I'm using on my last proyect because I'm building a HD art gallery so that why the first one is (max-width: 1079px), but you can adjust these based on your needs... good luck